# Do i have to have a billing account to use Google Maps Api keys?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't have a billing account but I still have access to Google Cloud Platform and I can make API keys for my Android project,

[image: 2 API keys from google]
I already have two API keys and they seem to work but when I add them to my project I get an empty activity at first and then the cashed map loads (I'm doing a zoom-in animation to a certain location but map only loads after the animation ends ) and I tried to put a made up API key instead and still I get the same behavior so that confirms my theory that the API keys I have from google are not working.

My question is Do I have to have a billing account to use Google Maps API keys? although the gave me two keys and they seem to work

and is there a way to test API keys outside of the android studio to know for sure?

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was wrong. You do need a billing account setup to use the google maps platform.

> To use Google Maps Platform, you must have a billing account. The billing account is used to track costs associated with your projects. Make sure you understand how the billing account credits work.

https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#create-billing-account

Comment: hi i have a api key from a project that is not billing enabled... but it seems to work on my android project ... is that fine?... or will it cause problem while moving to production?